# AWX REST API - List Inventory returning null

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

**Environment:**

AWX: 3.0.1
Ansible: 2.7.8

Greetings fellows. Having a problem listing organization in AWX via REST API. This is a brand-new installation. What has been done so far:

1. Organization Created
2. Users created
3. Users added to Organization
4. Users assigned Permissions ('admin' here)

Now, I can obtain a token ,no problem. Using this **$token**, I am trying to list inventories:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization:Token $token" -f -k -H "content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://192.168.2.37/api/v2/organizations | jq .

$
```

...and getting null. I don't understand what is going on. It is authenticating me.

Any feedback or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: in prior versions of AWX when it used `authtoken` instead of oauth2, the cURL directive was "`Authorization: Token <your token>`". Now that AWX is using oauth2, I must have used "`Bearer <token>`" instead.